Clarification on Undefined Behavior Surrounding reinterpret_cast<>
I've done a lot of reading recently on reinterpret_cast as I want to ensure I'm using it correctly and not accidentally invoking undefined behavior. I feel like cppreference and this great writeup on strict aliasing has me 95% of the way there, but I wanted some clarification on my understanding of what is, and is not UB.
Let's say I have a struct:
struct __attribute__((packed)) SimpleStruct {
    uint32_t a = 0;
    uint8_t b = 1;
    int16_t c = 2;
    uint8_t d[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
};

I've used the __attribute__((packed)) directive to ensure no padding bytes are used, to the detriment of performance/optimizations. Per the standard, examining the byte representation via a reinterpret_cast to unsigned char * of the object is allowed, and not UB:
unsigned char *bytes_of_simple_struct = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&simple_struct);

Now, and this is the part I wanted clarification on, I believe modifying bytes of the struct via this pointer is also allowed, and not UB (assuming you obey the size of the object):
static_assert(sizeof(simple_struct) == 12);
bytes_of_simple_struct[0] = 0x1U;

Now, I understand that what the value of simple_struct.a will be depends on endianness of the system. However, accessing simple_struct.a post this modification of bytes is still defined behavior correct? Because as long as I haven't modified the bytes to be an invalid representation of the type they make up, behavior should still be defined.
Conversely, if my struct had a bool instead:
struct __attribute__((packed)) SimpleStruct {
    bool a_bool = false;
    uint8_t b = 1;
    int16_t c = 2;
    uint8_t d[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
};

Then doing something like this:
bytes_of_simple_struct[0] = 0xFFU;
assert(simple_struct.a_bool == false);

Would be invoking UB, since I've now modified the underlying bytes of a_bool such that there is not valid representation of type bool. Basically, as long as any byte modification still obeys the rules for what bytes can represent each type, behavior should be defined? And in the case of the basic numeric types, you can essentially modify the bytes to anything (whether or not this is useful is another story), as any byte value is a valid uint8_t, any two bytes are a valid uint16_t, etc...
Is my understanding correct?

IANALL.  I believe your understanding is correct, and your awareness of when things go badly (UB), such as putting a bad representation of bits in a bool.

simple_struct.a would have unspecified value, unless the bytes you put into it are a copy of the representation of another uint32_t object. It could even be a trap representation, on the (nowadays mostly theoretical) system that has those. Same with simple_struct.a_bool (a bool holding an unspecified value may behave as if it's neither true nor false).

You can only write to the byte representation if you are copying the bytes of another object into it.  You can't just arbitrarily write to the object.

@IgorTandetnik agreed as long as you are being specific with your use of "unspecified". This does not form "undefined behavior", but rather the values themselves can be "unspecified", meaning it's up to you to know how your compiler/system architecture represents types as bytes.

@NathanOliver can you find where in the standard it says that? I'm not trying to be difficult Im just legitimately curious where that is disallowed. This is kind of the lynchpin of why I asked this question. If I can memcpy a 4 byte unsigned char array into a uint32_t, and that is considered well defined by the standard and I can ALSO reinterpret_cast a uint32_t to an unsigned char pointer and that is well defined, is modifying a byte via that pointer really different than the memcpy case?

I think it is a corollary of basic.types.general, which talks only about copying complete objects, not partial objects or single bytes of objects. Therefore, changing just a single byte is undefined behavior.

@haydenridd - memcpy is magic, in that it can create objects in the target space. Assigning byte by byte probably cannot. So this rabbit hole is deep!

The thing is, whether it's "undefined" or not doesn't really matter from a practical perspective; I'll leave that to the theoretical discussions. You are simply doing "implementation dependent" things, so you're sacrificing portability (to other platforms or even a new version of your compiler) in order to create unreadable code. Really, what's the point in that? Arguably, you can dump this particular struct into a file and read it back -- as long as the same implementation that wrote it also reads it, you'll be fine. But still, I'd question whether I'd really want to do it that way.

@ChristianStieber in my specific case, my target is an embedded MCU, and I store configuration data in an off-chip flash IC that is write/read using low level C APIs that look like writeFlash(uint32_t addr, const uint8_t *data, uint32_t size), readFlash(uint32_t addr, uint8_t *data, uint32_t size). Let's say I'm storing ~1KB worth of data, my "defined" options are somewhat limited. I can:

Read + parse data in chunks and manually populate my struct
Read into a temporary buffer that is sizeof(MyStruct) and memcpy() (defined, but in my world tossing another 1KB on the fire is a lot)


For anyone who may find this helpful, a nice summary on what I was missing about undefined behavior in the form of some commented code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cassert>

struct __attribute__((packed)) SimpleStruct
{
  bool a_bool = false;
  uint8_t b = 1;
  int16_t c = 2;
  uint8_t d[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
};

int
main ()
{

    SimpleStruct simple_struct{};

    // Ensuring padding has indeed been removed from the struct with __attribute__((packed)) 
    static_assert (sizeof (simple_struct) == 10);

    // Defined behavior, casting to unsigned char (or std::byte in C++20) to view the byte representation of an object is allowed
    unsigned char *bytes_of_simple_struct =
    reinterpret_cast <unsigned char *>(&simple_struct);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (simple_struct); i++)
    {
        printf("Byte %d of struct: %02X\n", i, bytes_of_simple_struct[i]);
    }
    
    // Defined behavior, using memcpy() to copy bytes into an object is allowed
    static_assert(sizeof(bool) == 1);
    uint8_t byte_array[sizeof(SimpleStruct)] = {
        0x00U, // Critical this is either 0x00U or 0x01U, the only two valid byte representations for type bool
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
        0x00U,
    };
    static_assert(sizeof(simple_struct) == sizeof(byte_array));
    memcpy(&simple_struct, byte_array, sizeof(simple_struct));
    assert(simple_struct.b == 0);
    
    // Undefined behavior! This violates strict aliasing, because:
    // - bytes_of_simple_struct[1] - Undefined! We've now de-referenced the unsigned char *,
    //                               but the unsigned char * actually points at a SimpleStruct!
    //                               Assigning values as if it was an unsigned char is undefined.
    bytes_of_simple_struct[1] = 0xFFU;
    assert(simple_struct.b = 0xFFU);
    
    // A subtly different way to assign a single byte to bytes_of_simple_struct[1] that is defined.
    // While it looks similar, the entire reason this is "defined" is because memcpy is not
    // interpreting simple_struct as any type, it is simply copying bytes from one memory
    // location to another.
    unsigned char a_byte = 0xFFU;
    memcpy(bytes_of_simple_struct + 1, &a_byte, sizeof(a_byte));
    assert(simple_struct.b = 0xFFU);
    
    // However, extreme care must be taken to ensure that the byte representation of the
    // type being copied into is still valid post memcpy(). If the byte representation isn't
    // valid, undefined behavior still occurs. For example:
    a_byte = 0xFFU;
    memcpy(bytes_of_simple_struct, &a_byte, sizeof(a_byte));
    
    // A bool can only be represented by bytes 0x0 and 0x1, by copying 0xFF into a bool type
    // and referencing simple_struct.a_bool, undefined behavior is invoked.
    // For example, these assertions both pass compiled with GCC 13.2!
    assert(simple_struct.a_bool != false);
    assert(simple_struct.a_bool != true)
    
}


